# Правильная организация Django проекта в Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

Подскажите как правильно создать Images с docker-compose, если есть проект Django с несколькими приложениями *A, B, C*.

С докером знакомлюсь из любопытства и исходя из того что пока знаю, появилось 2 варианта, подскажите какой правильный или может я вообще ничего не понял):

**1).** - На самом VPS устанавливаем Docker, клонируем репозиторий Django с названием проекта app, внутри него рядом с приложениями *A, B, C* создаём Dockerfile, requirements.txt и тд...
Итог - Получаем 1 Image

**2).** - На самом VPS устанавливаем Django, создаём проект app и внутри каждого приложения (*A, B, C*) создаём Dockerfile.
Итог - Получаем 3 Images

Comment: Что-то я не понял, как вы в принципе собрались реализовывать пункт 2, если Django-приложения неразрывно связаны друг с другом

Comment: да вот начитался что можно реализовать как микросервисы отдельные приложение, к примеру A - сервис авторизации, B - сервис с картинками и тд... и думал возможно это тоже так сработает
Возникли вот такие мысли, хотел услышать мнение людей

Comment: Можно, но каждый из них будет полностью отдельным проектом (а иначе в микросервисах нет смысла)

Comment: понял, спасибо большое